# How can I find the location of my current user account picture?

Tags: macos, high-sierra

five years ago, I uploaded a photo as my account picture. 
I tried the ways below, but I still cannot find the location to find the original picture.

my macOS high sierra 10.13.4

~/Library/Containers/

cannot find

com.apple.ImageKit

or

iChat Recent Pictures

and
even /Library/User Pictures cannot find

Comment: Since user accounts can be local or remote, these are embedded in structured preference lists for local accounts on macOS. The location is basically the same since early OS X but the implementation has changed slightly. Looks like you have a solid answer to where the processed image is stored. It’s unlikely the original was retained if you don’t have a backup of the source.

Answer (score 2):

You can run the following command from terminal to get your user account pictures. This would be an easy way.

```
dscl . -read /Users/Yourusername JPEGPhoto | tail -1 | xxd -r -p > accountImage.jpg
```

Just you will get a 256x256 pixel version of your account picture